# Galois group for $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n + \zeta_n^{-1})/\mathbb{Q})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-extensions

I want to find, classify $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n + \zeta_n^{-1})/\mathbb{Q})$ group up to isomorphism where $\zeta_n = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}$. I know $\zeta_n$ is a root of $x^2 - (\zeta_n + \zeta_n^{-1})x +1$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n) : \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n + \zeta_n^{-1}) ]=2$ for $n>2$.

My background of Galois theory is the very basic definition. i.e., it is an algebraic normal separable extension and if $E$ is Galois over $F$, $|Gal(E/F)|=[E:F]$.

So if I know correctly, to use the above results, I need to show $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n + \zeta_n^{-1})$ is Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$, what is the nice way to showing this?

Comment: Can you compute the Galois group $G$ of $\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)/\mathbb Q$? By the fundamental theorem, $\mathbb Q(\zeta_n + \zeta_n^{-1})$ will be the fixed field of some subgroup $H\subset G$ of order $[\mathbb Q(\zeta_n):\mathbb Q(\zeta_n + \zeta_n^{-1})]=2$, which you can compute by using the explicit presentation of $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)/\mathbb Q)$ as $(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^\times$. Its Galois group will be $G/H$.

Comment: Well, your field is not anything *over* $\Bbb Q(\zeta_n)$, since it’s a subfield. I think you mean to ask for its properties over $\Bbb Q$. In that case, since $\Bbb Q(\zeta_n)$ is abelian over $\Bbb Q$, all intermediate fields are Galois over $\Bbb Q$, and there’s no work involved.

Comment: @Lubin. I see,  Since $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)/\mathbb{Q}$ is an abelian extension, any intermeidate fields are Galois(abelian) extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, hence $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n + \zeta_n^{-1})/\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois(abelian)